# How can I change the background color of a certain area above the footer as shown in the photo? I'm using wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I change the background color of a certain area above the footer as shown in the photo? I'm using WordPress, the theme is fusion if anyone is familiar with.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to do]

I can't determine the id of this exact section shown in the image. 
can anyone help me with that problem?

Comment: I edited it, the website didn't post the photo.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Hi Mariam. Unfortunately, no one will be able to help you without looking at some code. We can't guess what the ID is either by just looking at a picture. Please share your site's URL or provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the website is not live yet.

Comment: If its WordPress you need to change the documentation files, they probably have footer.php, so try finding it and see what CSS its using, locate it and design footer as you wish, background-color: yourcolor; will fix it if theres no background image.